# How to get path from URL when filename contains question mark

Tags: ruby

I have a url like this:

`url = www.example.com/resources/am_i_a_file?.pdf`

where the filename contains a question mark (I know....)

When I try the following:

```
uri = URI::parse(url)
path_raw = uri.path
```

I get: ***resources/am_i_a_file***

I can understand why this is the case but ideally I would want to get: ***resources/am_i_a_file?.pdf***

Comment: _"I have a url like this"_ – where does it come from? If `?` is supposed to be part of the path, it has to be percent encoded, i.e. `am_i_a_file%3F.pdf`

Comment: The url comes from a link in a text document that I'm importing, using Nokogiri I am rewriting the href value to point at the new location of the file that was also imported as part of the operation. Unfortunately the href on the link does not encode the filename

Comment: @MarkKenny given the example you could just use `to_s` instead of `path` e.g. `uri.to_s #=> "www.example.com/resources/am_i_a_file?.pdf"`

Comment: if it is part of the path, then it needs to be percent-encoded. don't try to fix the URL parsing, fix the scraping/parsing that leads to this broken input.

Comment: Since a query string usually doesn't consist of a file extension, you could use that for a quick and dirty pattern matching, e.g. `url.sub(/\?(?=\.\w+$)/, '%3F')`

Comment: @Stefan. Apologies as I realise that this is simply a string and not a direct url. I can confirm that a "dirty" substitution of the '?' in hand does work for this rare case. I do think that I'll explore what Pascal says too in order to catch any other oddities that might arise from this.  Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

You could approach it in this manner: initially substitute the ? with its URL-encoded form prior to parsing the URL, and subsequently revert it back to ? once you have obtained the path.

```
require 'uri'
url = 'www.example.com/resources/am_i_a_file?.pdf'
encoded_url = url.gsub('?', '%3F')
uri = URI::parse(encoded_url)
path_raw = uri.path.gsub('%3F', '?')
p path_raw
```

Output

```
"www.example.com/resources/am_i_a_file?.pdf"
```